# Deserialize Json with T literal

Tags: java, json, spring

I receive a json with a date formatted like this:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
```

But I can't deserialize it properly. I've tried with something like this:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
private SimpleDateFormat createdAt;
```

with Jackson deserializers and with different types. Nothings works.

Comment: This link can help you - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have received following JSON;

```
{"item":{"title":"my title","expires":"2017-01-07T18:46:19Z"}}
```

**Item.java:**

```
@JsonRootName("item")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Item {
 public String title;
 public Date expires;

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "Item{" +
       "title='" + title + '\'' +
       ", expires=" + expires +
      '}';
 }
}
```

Configure the `ObjectMapper` with `DateFormat`you want to use.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));

    Item t1 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Item.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing SimpleDateFormat to Date

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
private Date createdAt;
```

TestCase :

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{

        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();     
        SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Date date=new Date();       
        TestClass test= new TestClass();
        test.setCreatedAt(date);
        String input=mapper.writeValueAsString(test);   
        TestClass testClass=(TestClass)mapper.readValue(input,TestClass.class);
        System.out.println("testClass"+testClass.toString());
    }

        @JsonRootName("test")
        protected static class TestClass{

            @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") 
            private Date createdAt;

       }
```

Response:

```
 input:   {"createdAt":"2017-01-07T17:51:03+0000"}
  output :testClass [createdAt=Sat Jan 07 23:21:03 IST 2017]
```